# What does Hinduism have to say about the laws of war?

Tags: belief, war

I am interested in general to learn about this subject. More specifically I was wondering if according to Hinduism would it be legal for a Hindu majority state to launch a preemptive strike on Rome if it was clear Rome had designs on Hindu territory and on the forced mass conversion of Hindu believers? Or would there have to be some other stronger justification?

Comment: I would suggest looking into Mahabharta or Dhanurvedam, the latter a group in which texts fall under as treatsies of archery, but more broadly discuss war, the latter a famous epic with political and moral themes and a grand war.